# required to have flask static folder outside of project root

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a requirement to store all static files outside of project folder. though i updated my flask config like below it still not saving images in that folder...

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../Storage/static', static_url_path='/storage')
```

but when i try to save file with below code it always store images inside project_folder->static

```
def save_image(image: FileStorage, folder: str = None, name: str = None) -> str:
    return IMAGE_SET.save(image, folder, name)
```

the requirement example:

current

```
project_folder/
               static/
                      images/
```

required to store like

```
Storage(parallel folder)/
               static/
                     images/
```

Please help, 
I tried with below links but not helped...

[Flask not recognising static folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521358/flask-not-recognising-static-folder)

[How do i link to images not in Static folder in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971491/how-do-i-link-to-images-not-in-static-folder-in-flask)

[Change static folder from config in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346486/change-static-folder-from-config-in-flask)

[Setting my <img> source to a file path outside of flask static folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862094/setting-my-img-source-to-a-file-path-outside-of-flask-static-folder)

Answer (score 0):

below are my test code,
the folder '../Storage/static/images' should be made before run the code or use os.makedirs() to make first:

```
import sys,os
from flask import  Flask
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
file = None
fp=open('110326-666286.jpg', 'rb')
file = FileStorage(fp)

app=Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True

def save_image(image: FileStorage, folder: str = None, name: str = None) -> str:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)
    return image.save(folder+'/'+name)

@app.route('/hello/<name>/<surname>')
def hello(name,surname):
  save_image(file,'../Storage/static/images','110326-666286_.jpg')
  if os.path.exists('../Storage/static/images'+'/'+'110326-666286_.jpg'):
    res='image saved'
  else:
    res='image not saved'
  return '<h1>hello, %s %s</h1><p>%s</p>'%(name,surname,res)



if __name__=='__main__':
  app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8080)
```

below is the result

[image]